# Cinda CUDA Driver Problem when trying to Install CartoPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, cartopy

I've been trying to install CartoPy recently. I have all the dependencies that CartoPy requires, but when I try to install through the Anaconda Navigator, I'm given this message:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your
environment:

Specifications:

- cartopy -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version
you've asked for.

When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the
left is somehow not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

- feature:/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 11.0
```

I'm confused with the last part of the error message, because the CUDA drivers are matching versions (`11.0`). I've googled around, and have seen similar problems, but none that explicitly mention CartoPy, and the responses are a bit over my head.

How do I fix this error? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the main channel for Anaconda doesn't currently have a build of CartoPy for Python 3.8. You'll either need to change to Python 3.7, or install from conda-forge--but I don't know how to add a channel to Anaconda Navigator. So the path I'd take would be:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.8 cartopy 
conda activate myenv
```

To create a new environment with cartopy and activate it from the command line.